# Reading a file using argc and argv

Tags: c, arrays, file, argv

I'm trying to (as the title says) read  from a file into main, using argc and argv, taking the filename from the command line and passing it through main into a void function which opens, reads and writes it. However im getting `Cannot open file...` `Segmentation fault`.

```
void file_pass (char * argv[])
{

FILE *file_name;
if ((file_name = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file ...\n");
    }

fclose(file_name);

}
```

Which leads me to think it isn't opening the file correctly but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Please stop destroying your questions after they've been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function `void file_pass (char * argv[])` -

```
if ((file_name = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
```

Instead of this , you should try this -

```
if ((file_name = fopen(argv[0], "r")) == NULL)   // file's name is in argv[0] in funciton
```

Because array indexing start with `0` and in function `argv[1]` may contain nothing .

Comment: That works perfectly. Strange thought, I thought argv[0] was always the program name, and argv[1] in this case would be the inputted file name?

Comment: Ahhh I see. C is so fickle :D

Comment: @Finlandia_C Yeah , it may get a little tricky when passing arrays :)

Comment: @Finlandia_C In this copy will not be created as address of `argv[1]` is passed , so `argv[0]` will contain value at that address , that is value of `argv[1]` . The above comment I mentioned is wrong I think .